# ASA Error -157: Cannot convert 2006 05 29 04:00 to a timestamp

Tags: soap, sybase-asa, ojdbc

I am encoutering this error while inserting timestamp value into the sybase any where database.
Any help
com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: ASA Error -157: Cannot convert 2006 05 29 04:00 to a timestamp
; nested exception is:
BINDING.JCA-11811
Stored procedure invocation error.
Error while trying to prepare and execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format to be passed is kind of different it expects the date in the following format

DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS

Where DD is date in numeric eg: 09
Where MMM is month in abbrev form eg:JUN for july
where YYYY is year in 4 digits eg: 2013

hh:mm:ss is the time stamp without timezone